# Snowflake: Transform data while storing

Tags: azure-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I am trying to pull data from one snowflake warehouse1/DB into another warehouse2/DB. Data stored in warehouse1 is raw data and while storing that data in warehouse2 I want it to be transformed. Transformation is done in terms of changing the units of values. I have close to 1000 units and each unit has a factor value associated with it. When the data is pulled from warehouse1 I want to check what its current unit is, and convert that into another unit by multiplying its value with a factor. I want to host this unit data somewhere so that it can be referred to during each data ingestion process. This process needs to be scheduled on an hourly basis.

The raw data can be millions of rows and the solution needs to be feasible in handling that much of data, transform it and store it time efficiently.

So far I have read about using Azure Data Factory pipelines to pull the data from Snowflake and store it in another warehouse. But I need some suggestions if there are any better tools available to achieve this. Any sample, documentation will be helpful.

Comment: You do not need any tool to do the transformation. It's a well established pattern to do transformation in the database.  1. Copy into a staging table (using ADF or snowpipe or `create clone`; 2. run an `UPDATE` to update the values with your factor 3. Run an insert / delete / update to merge it into the target. ADF only supports inline transformation using data flows, and that requires databricks (i.e. compute cost and spin up time).

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Where I can store this units, factors data? I can have it as a JSON data or does ADF supports temporary table in which I can store this data and refer at time of updating the values?

Comment: Are these 2 databases in the same Snowflake account?

Comment: @NickW They are part of same account but in different warehouses and can be accessed using different roles.

Comment: Why don't you store this data in a snowflake table? You'll need to in order to apply update transformations

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid right I can have it as a table data in Snowflake. But this units data I will be referring while pulling data from other warehouses also. So i was kind of looking at a solution to host it rather than creating same table in each warehouse.

Comment: As long as you set up the permissions correctly, all data in a Snowflake account is available to a single role/user. You don't need to create the same table in both DBs, just create it in one or create a new DB specifically for holding data that is generic across the account rather than specific to a DB.

Comment: BTW in Snowflake the term "warehouse" has a very specific meaning: it is a "compute engine". It's arguably a really bad term for Snowflake to have chosen, as it means something else to everyone involved with data warehousing, but we're stuck with it. So for the sake of clarity, please don't use the term "warehouse" unless you actually mean a Snowflake warehouse.

Comment: @NickW thank you. I will surely explore option of accessing table created in another DB for doing the data transformation.